# fetch primary key from core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, primary-key, fetch

I like to fetch all objects of entity primary key. How I should implement it? How I retrieve ids from it?

This code recommended:

```
[NSManagedObject objectID].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the object id you can call

```
  NSManagedObject *object = [managedObjectContex objectForID:objectId]
```

to retrieve the corresponding object.

As you also recommend you cna get the id with

```
  NSManagedObjectID *moID = [managedObject objectID];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fetch and then access objects is:

```
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* items = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObjectID* objectID in items) {
        NSManagedObject* object = [context objectWithID:objectID];
        ...
    }
```

Comment: thank you for good help,but received id is changing every time and i need id that should not change .

Comment: What do you mean 'but received id is changing every time'? Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: first time i received id is different than second time i recieved .Is this recieved id is primery key or temporary key .

Comment: A managed object ID uniquely identifies the same managed object  between managed object contexts in a single application (From Apple Docs). If your context has no unsaved changes then IDs can't be temporary. Just in case check BOOL isTemporary = [objectID isTemporaryID];

Comment: look one place i got,   NSManagedObject* object = [context objectWithID:objectID];

Comment: Ur expalined code is completely good tanks  ,look here, i got object id and in next view i wanna fetch same id object with new  managedobjectcontext how i strore id of object and can i get the same object again .

Comment: Definitely yes. Just do the same thing with another context NSManagedObject* object = [anotherContext objectWithID:objectID]; and you will get the same object but  in new context.